# Specialized numerical method for transcendental equation

Tags: numerical-methods, transcendental-equations

Is there any specialized, very fast, numerical method for solving equations of a type
$$
  e^{-px-q} = \frac{ax^2 + bx + c}{kx + l}
$$
wher all $ a, p, q $ are strictly positive? To be more precise, is there anything that I could use except bisection, regula falsi, or Newton-Raphson's method? Maybe in combination with something specific?

Comment: @Amzoti No, everything is OK with usual root-finding algorithms. I was just curious if there are specialized algorithms, which have very good performance. Thnaks Amzoti.